# How to maintain the TCP connection using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, tcpsocket

Using `TCPSocket`, I need to `socket.puts "foobar"`, and then `socket.close` to let the socket in the other side `socket.read`  the message.

Is there a way to send or receive a message though a socket, but without closing the socket, which mean I can send message again without creating a socket again?

p.s Something like websocket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you traverse up the super class chain you will eventually see that you inherit from [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html). Most `IO` objects, in Ruby, buffer the data to be more efficient writing and reading from disk.

In your case, the buffer wasn't large enough (or enough time didn't pass) for it to flush out. However, when you closed the socket, this forced a flush of the buffer resources.

You have a few options:

- You can manually force the buffer to flush using [`IO#flush`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-flush).
- You can set the buffer to always sync after a write / read, by setting [`IO#sync=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) to `true`. You can check the status of your `IO` object's syncing using [`IO#sync`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-sync); I'm guessing you'd see `socket.sync #=> false`
- Use [`BasicSocket#send`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/BasicSocket.html#method-i-send) which will [call](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/socket/init.c#L86) POSIX [`send(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send); since sockets are [initialized](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/socket/init.c#L67) with [`O_FSYNC`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/io.c#L5526-5530) set, the send will be synchronous and atomic.

Comment: One should not have to set `sync` on sockets. Looking at the source, sockets are [initialized](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/socket/init.c#L67) with [`O_FSYNC`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/io.c#L5526-5530) set and [`#send`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/socket/basicsocket.c#L561-L573) just calls POSIX [`send(2)`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/socket/init.c#L86)

Comment: Hmmm, overlooked that OP was using `puts`, not `send`, that does go through internal buffering logic controlled by `sync`

Comment: Great answer! I've tried all three solution, all works, and thanks for  point out the underlying POSIX operation

Answer (score 1):

It should not be neccessary to close the connection in order for the other party to read it. `send` should transfer the data over the conection immediately. Make sure the other party is reading from the socket.